# Prove that an exponential martingale $X_n$ converges almost surely and in $L^2$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, suppose that $\{Y_n : n \geq 1 \}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with common distribution $N(0,1)$. Let $\{a_n : n \geq 1 \}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Set $X_0 \equiv 1$ and for $n \geq 1$,
$$ X_n := \text{exp} \bigg ( \sum_{j=1}^n a_j Y_j - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2 \bigg )$$
Prove the following:

1. If $\sum_{j=1}^n a_n^2 < \infty$, then there exists $X \in L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ such that $X_n \to X$ both almost surely and in $L^2$.
2. If $\sum_{j=1}^n a_n^2 = \infty$, then $X_n \to 0$ almost surely.

My attempt so far:

We have $\text{log}(X_n) = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j Y_j - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2$ for $n \geq 1$. Hence,

$$\begin{align} 
E[\text{log}(X_n)] &= E \bigg [\sum_{j=1}^n a_j Y_j - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2 \bigg ] \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \big ( a_j E[Y_j] \big ) - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^na_j^2 \\
&= - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^na_j^2.
\end{align}$$
I'm not sure if the above result can be useful to me. I'm still new to working with probability theory, so I'm just not sure what result I need to use to help tie this all together. I would be super appreciative if someone could help point me in the right direction.

---

Update: I have left my original question and attempt so that the comments posted still make sense, but my major problem when attempting this problem was that I had not yet been introduced to martingales. Now that I have been introduced to some martingale theory, I have worked out the following :

- $E[X_n] = 1$ $\forall n \geq 0$
- $E[X_n^2] = \text{exp}(\sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2)$ $\forall n \geq 1$

and so, since $X_n$ is a martingale (with respect to the natural filtration), we can say by the martingale convergence theorem that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2 < \infty$, then there exists $X \in L^2$ such that $X_n \to X$ both almost surely and in $L^2$.

However, I'm still stuck trying to prove that when $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2 = \infty$ we have $X_n \to 0$ almost surely. I started by defining:

- $Z_n := a_nY_n - \frac{1}{2} a_n^2$
- $W_n := \sum_{j=1}^n Z_j$

so that $Z_n \sim N(- \frac{1}{2} a_n^2, a_n^2)$, $W_n \sim N(- \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2, \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2)$ and $X_n = \text{exp} (W_n)$. After this, I tried a number of different approaches, including to try some kind of law of large numbers on $Z_n$, or by considering something like $P(X_n \geq \epsilon)$ and then applying Borel-Cantelli. In all cases, I end up stuck and unable to prove the result. If anyone has any hints/suggestions I would appreciate them greatly.

Comment: $E[X_n] \ne \exp(E[\log(X_n)])$ unless $X_n$ is deterministic because of Jensen's inequality.  We actually have $E[X_n] = 1$.

Comment: Can you explain a little more how exactly you arrived at that result? I see that I am wrong in my attempt. Should I remove my attempt or leave it up?

Comment: Can you give some ideas of the results and techniques that you know and could use?  Do you know about martingales?  Uniform integrability?  Borel-Cantelli?  Do you know how to compute $E[\exp Y]$ for $Y \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$?

Comment: You should definitely leave up your attempt.  You can compute $E[X_n]$ by just integrating the function against the pdf of $Y_n$.  It would probably be easiest to use independence so you just need to compute $E[\exp(a_n Y_n - \frac 12 a_n^2)]$ and take the product.

Comment: I know uniform integrability and Borel-Cantelli. I don't know martingales or how to compute $E[\text{exp}(Y)]$ where $Y$ is normally distributed (not yet, anyways). I am trying to solve these problems as a form of self-study (extra practice for a course I am taking). Maybe this is above what I am capable of solving with my current knowledge? When I saw this problem, I thought it would be something related to LLN, given the questions ask for a.s. convergence.