# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2 = \infty$ & $Y_n \sim N(0,1)$ iid, $\bigg ( \sum_{j=1}^n a_j Y_j - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2 \bigg ) \to - \infty$ a.s.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

This question is based on a previous question I posted, however, at the time I was not familiar with martingale theory, so I was unable to approach the problem (original question here: [Prove that a particular sequence of random variables $X_n$ converges almost surely and in $L^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306427/prove-that-a-particular-sequence-of-random-variables-x-n-converges-almost-sure) ).

I have since learned more about martingales, and I was able to solve the first part. Now, I'm stuck with solving a problem which relies on proving that if $\{Y_n : n \geq 1 \}$ are i.i.d. with $Y_n \sim N(0,1)$ and $\{a_n : n \geq 1\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a sequence satisfying $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j^2 = \infty$, then $\bigg ( \sum_{j=1}^n a_j Y_j - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2 \bigg ) \to - \infty$ almost surely.

Naturally, my first approach has been to try and apply some kind of law of large numbers to this problem, but all my attempts keep running in to problems. First off, if I tried defining $W_j := a_j Y_j$, so that $W_j \sim N(0, a_j^2)$. Hence, I have a sequence of random variables with $E[W_j] = 0 \ \forall j \geq 1$. However, it doesn't look like I have any control over $\text{Var}(W_j) = a_j^2$, since it could be $a_j \to \infty$ or $a_j \to 0$ as $j \to \infty$.

Likewise, I thought about $\big (\sum_{j=1}^n W_j \big ) \sim N(0, \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2)$, but I couldn't find a way to use this either. My main problem seems to be that none of these random variables are i.i.d., and so this makes solving the problem more challenging. I am familiar with different laws of large numbers (Rajchman and Kolmogorov), some basic martingale convergence theory, and the Borel-Cantelli lemmas, but so far I am still stuck proving this point. If anyone has any suggestion, hints, or solutions I would appreciate hearing the immensely.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out, I have fixed that

Comment: Hint: $\bigg ( \sum_{j=1}^n a_j Y_j - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2 \bigg ) \sim N(- \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2 ,  \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2) = N(-b_n, 2b_n), b_n =2 \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2 \to +\infty$.  Then use smth.like Proposition 5.34 here: \www.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~mjmorais/Chapter5incomplete.pdf

Comment: I think I see it. If $W_n \sim N(-b_n, 2b_n)$ as you defined and I consider $P(|W_n| \geq \epsilon)$, then I need an upper bound for this probability. To apply Borel-Cantelli, I would need something that is summable. I know that for $X \sim N(0,1)$, I have $P(X \geq t) \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \pi} \frac{1}{t} \text{exp}( - \frac{t^2}{2})$, which should hopefully be summable when I apply it to this problem.